# Can you 'redeclare' a variable in a subclass?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to declare that a member is a subclass of the base classes member?

E.g.

```
class A {
    int a;
}

class B : A {
    int b;
}

class Foo {
   A *baz;
}

class Bar : Foo {
   B *baz; //How can I not shadow baz, but 'redeclare' it as a B?
}
```

Basically, Bar will always have baz be a B and I want 2 things: a way of showing/enforcing this and also avoiding to have to cast baz everytime its used in Bar. My intuition is that this is not possible, but I dont purport to be a C++ expert.

Comment: It sounds like templates *might* be a solution here; i.e. `class Foo<T> { T *baz; }; class Bar : Foo<B> { ... };`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth you should make your comment an answer. It looks like the best solution so far.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, this loses the inheritance relationship between Foo<A> and Bar<B>.

Comment: @zmbq: Absolutely.  It's not clear whether that's important, though.

Comment: Is baz private by accident?

Comment: @zmbq not by accident, but I wrote it that way just for the sake of brevity (i thought that the point got across this way and was overall more clear)

Comment: If baz is private, this *might* be possible, as Foo::baz in inaccessible from Bar. Best way to test it is to try it out - what happens when you compile the code?

Comment: @zmbq I meant that baz is supposed to be protected/public, but omitted it because I thought you could easily understand it to be without explicitly saying so.

Comment: Too bad, I just tried this out, and if baz is private you can do that without a problem (at least on the latest clang).

Comment: Oh, you don't want to shadow it, but redeclare it as a different type. It would make no sense, as it might totally break Foo - what if a Foo method tries to assign an A into baz?

Comment: @zmbq C and C++, unlike Java, make no (little) attempt to stop you from shooting yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. You can only redeclare a return type of a virtual function.

```
class Foo {
   virtual A *baz();
};

class Bar : public Foo {
   B *baz();
};
```

Comment: @Oktalist it makes sense, you can override methods and the return type is not part of the function signature.

Comment: @chacham15 but the return types must be compatible. If e.g. `Foo::baz` returned `double` and `Bar::baz` returned `int` then it would be ill formed.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how `baz` is initialized in `Foo`. This is a possible solution:

```
class Foo {
protected:
   A *baz;

public:
   Foo() : baz(new A) {}
   Foo(A *baz_) : baz(baz_) {}
   // dtor, copy ctor, copy assign operator required but skipped for brevity
}

class Bar : Foo {
public:
   Bar() : Foo(new B) {}

private:
   // use this to access baz as a B*
   B *baz() { return static_cast<B*>(Foo::baz); }
}
```

A smart pointer would be preferred over a raw pointer here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'redeclare' any name in C++, but here you're not.  Within `Bar`, `baz` is the default with:

```
 baz
```

or

```
 Bar::baz
```

and you get to `Foo`'s with:

```
 Foo::baz
```

ypu see they have their own scope and therefore unique name.